# VBA Selenium How can block the file upload window dialog?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I'm making a posting macro.

```
<input type="file" multiple="" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.png,.bmp,.heic,.heif" id="hidden-file" style="display: none;">
```

Above element occurs after click a file upload button.
Before click the button, above element is not exist.

I tried various method but problem is file upload window dialog.
Is there some way to block the file upload window dialog?

After click the button, if run below code, it works well.

```
DRIVER.FindElementById("hidden-file").SendKeys filepath
```

Comment: Please post some code that we can try out and the URL that you are using. Read this link about creating a Minimal Reprodicible Example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example